# How can I select the IP addresses that occur on different dates?

Tags: mysql

**Table**

```
| id | ip_address | timestamp  |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 1.1.1.1    | 1492781703 |
| 2  | 2.2.2.2    | 1492695303 |
| 3  | 3.3.3.3    | 1492608903 |
| 4  | 1.1.1.1    | 1492695303 |
```

**Desired output**

```
| id | ip_address | timestamp  |
--------------------------------
| 1  | 1.1.1.1    | 2017-04-21 |
| 4  | 1.1.1.1    | 2017-04-20 |
```

How can I select the IP addresses that occur on different dates?

NOTE: I do not know the IP addresses or the dates.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to approach this yourself? Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Convert timestamp in date and group by the records by formatted date. So there will be one record for one date.

```
select id,ip_address,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%e %b %Y') AS date_formatted from table group by DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), '%e %b %Y')
```

Comment: This is very wrong. The query gets you one row per day, each with one of the IDs of the day arbitrarily chosen and one of the IP addresses that occurred the day, also arbitrarily chosen. @user557108: Have you read my comment to your request? What about thinking of an approach to the problem, rather than waiting for someone to write you a query?